# Is it possible to reverse a regression analysis?

Tags: regression

For instance, the [YearPredictionMSD Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/YearPredictionMSD): it has 90 variables and 500k observations with which to predict the Year, using regression modeling.

Would it be possible to reverse this, and figure out which year had the largest impact on the variables?

Comment: Yes. You just make a new regression with the variable you want as dependent and year as a predictor.